# Return type of void async function in Dart

Tags: dart

In Dart, if you have an async function that doesn't return anything, should it return `Future<void>` or simply `void`? Both seem to work, but why?

```
void foo() async {
  print('foo');
}

Future<void> bar() async {
  print('bar');
}

void main() async {
  await foo();
  await bar();
  print('baz');
}
```

Compiles with no errors or warnings and prints

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Answer (score 4):

In your code, both functions `foo()` and `bar()` are not returning anything so **any function return type is valid for both functions** eg:

```
void/T/Future<T>... foo() async {
  print('foo');
}

Future<void>/T/Future<T>... bar() async {
  print('bar');
}
```

and here,

```
await foo();
await bar();
```

`await` just waits till the execution of these async functions is complete. As there is no return type, **await has no purpose here(redundant)** so this is and should not be a compilation error.

---

The difference is that `Future<void>` **gives you information of the execution** of the function like when the execution is complete and it also allows you to specify what to do when the function is executed by using `bar().then(...)` and `bar().whenComplete(...)`.

While `foo()` function return `void` and `void` does not hold as such any info like `Future<void>`. If you try to `await bar()` it will convert that `Future` object from `Future<void>` to `void`.

---

`Future` is just a container, with `await` returns the values once the async "tasks" are completed. Without `await`, `Future` objects give you information about the execution of the function from which they are returning.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the other answers - they were a little unclear to me so I'm just going to add some clarifications after experimenting on DartPad:

1. It is never an error *or even a warning!* to not return a value from a function, irrespective of the return type. This madness is presumably inherited from Javascript.
2. If you don't return from a function it implicitly returns `null`. Except in these cases:

   - If the return type is `void`, it does not return a value (and using the result of the expression is a compiler error).
   - If the function is `async`:

     - If the return type is `void`, you cannot use the result of the function, however you can still `await` it but you cannot use the result of the `await` expression, or use any methods of `Future`.
     - If the return type is `Future<void>` it returns an instance of `Future<void>`. You can `await` it, and call methods of `Future`, e.g. `.then((void v) { ... });`. However you cannot use the result of `await` (because it is `void`).
     - If the return type is `Future<T>` it returns an instance of `Future<T>` that resolves to `null`.

So basically, if you want to allow callers to use `Future` methods, you need to annotate the return type as `Future<void>`. If you merely want them to be able to `await` the function, you only need `void`. However since you probably don't know in advance I suspect it is a good idea to always use `Future<void>`.

Here's an example that demonstrates the possibilities:

```
// Compilation error - functions marked async must have a 
// return type assignable to 'Future'
// int int_async() async {
// }
void void_async() async {
}
Future<void> future_void_async() async {
}
Future<int> future_int_async() async {
}
int int_sync() {
}
void void_sync() {
}
Future<void> future_void_sync() {
}
Future<int> future_int_sync() {
}


void main() async {
  // print('${void_async()}'); // Compilation error - expression has type void.
  print('future_void_async: ${future_void_async()}');
  print('future_int_async: ${future_int_async()}');
  // print('${await future_void_async()}'); // Compilation error.
  await future_void_async();
  future_void_async().then((void v) {
    print('ok');
  });
  await void_async();
  // void_async().then((void v) { // Compilation error.
  //   print('ok');
  // });
  print('await future_int_async: ${await future_int_async()}');
  print('int_sync: ${int_sync()}');
  // print('${void_sync()}'); // Compilation error - expression has type void
  print('future_void_sync: ${future_void_sync()}');
  print('future_int_sync: ${future_int_sync()}');
}
```

It prints

```
future_void_async: Instance of '_Future<void>'
future_int_async: Instance of '_Future<int>'
ok
await future_int_async: null
int_sync: null
future_void_sync: null
future_int_sync: null
```

Comment: It is a warning to not return a value in a function with a return type.

Comment: It's a (linter) warning to `await` an `async` function that is declared as returning `void`: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/await_only_futures.html that's how I found this post. From everything I know so far, it seems like the async call would be awaited, but it's confusing, so maybe just don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think Future should be forced.

you can add avoid_void_async in your lint file:
https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_void_async.html

Answer (score 0):

A Future is simply a representation of an `Object` that hasn't completed the underlying function, and thus is a "promise" for later use. When you use `Future<void>`, there's no `Object` to return anyways, so it doesn't matter whether you use `void` or `Future<void>`. (The function doesn't return anything, so the return type is a placeholder anyways.)

However...
`Future<void>` can be used for listeners, and to check when things are complete, as can every `Future`. This means that you can use `Future`'s listeners to check for completion or errors in running your `Future<void> async` function, but not your `void async` function. Thus, in some cases, it's better to give `Future<void>` than `void` as the return type.